# Error: Configuration element is not declared

Tags: c#, xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
****<configuration>****
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

The above is one part of encoding in my program, which gives a error. Error is in the second line, which shows me something like a blue lined,

> configuration element is not declared

For what reason it happens like this?

Comment: Does your `xml` tag really not start with a `<`?

Comment: yes, the above code i have pasted is from my program

Comment: That'll be your problem, then. See LML's answer below.

Comment: Code is totally wrong. XML tag should start with `<` and there is no need of `****` before and after <configuration>

Comment: @MicrosoftDN - I could be wrong, but I suspect that's just the OP highlighting the line...

Answer (score 6):

Error due to the  missing '<' at start element

Change it to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
        </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: i have tried your program but it shows me the same error........ how to solve this any and can u tell me how to create a console apps exe in windows form application

Answer (score 1):

It gives an error on the *second* line? That's certainly odd, considering the missing '<' at the start of the first line. But the asterisks around the second line also clearly don't belong there.

How did you get this file? Where does it come from?

And have you tried this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Because that's what it probably should be.

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because you are missing '<' at start of the file